# how to displat SyncFusion Datetime picker Advanced

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to allow a user to select the date and time and I would like to know how would i achieve this with syncfusion Datetime Advance picker. I have tried using the syncfussion help but I don't see anything with regards to what I am trying to do.

Comment: It's a control. You pick it from the Toolbox and drop it on the form. Do you have a *specific* question or are you asking how the Windows Forms designer works?  Syncfusion's site and documentation *do* explain what the control's properties do. Working with the Forms designer though is covered in Visual Studio's beginner tutorials and videos

Comment: I had looked through the documentation and I could not find anything only after I went through more documentation did I find what I was looking for.  I was hoping that someone with better knowledge of the control would have been able to help, instead of stating the obvious about looking in the documentation.

Comment: Help with what? What *is* the problem? Did you add the control to the form? Did you try to edit its properties?